# std::vector swap causing memory fragmentation?

Tags: c++

I am currently working with very large data sets about 2.5GB worth of memory..

I am currently storing this by using a vector of class Data that contains 
1) Meta data
2) `boost::ptr_list<MemoryBlock>`

The MemoryBlock class contains
1) Meta Data
2) `std::vector<XYZ>`

When populating, i reserve my `std::vector<xyz>` in groups of 50,000. If the spatial dimensions of my vector grows to large, i will create a new memoryblock and use 
`std::vector<XYZ>(Points).swap(Points)` to shrink the vector to the proper size.

Now the problem...
It seems that when I use the swap trick to resize my array, I start to run into std::bad_alloc exceptions after clearing all of my data and loading in a new data set.

The amount of data that I can load in shrinks drastically... It will continue to do so every time I clear my data and load in a new data set...  For example, My initial data set will load in 100,000,000 values

next time it will load 70,000,000 values

Next time 50,000,000 values

next time 20,000,000 values
etc...

My first thought is a memory leak, but there is nothing I have been able to identify. Every thing in the code except for the swap has been used extensively for a very long time with out any problems.

If I do not use the swap/spatial dimension check, everything continues on and works properly.

any ideas?!?

*Edit*

```
bool Check_MemBlock_Size(MemoryBlock &CurrMemblock, XYZ CheckPoint){

    // Set a minimum of 5000 points in each memory block regardless of physical size..
    if(CurrMemblock.PointsArr.size() > 5000){
        XYZ TestMin, TestMax;
        TestMin = CurrMemblock.Min;
        TestMax = CurrMemblock.Max;

        // Check what the bounding box would be if we included the check point..
        if(TestMax.x < CheckPoint.x)
            TestMax.x = CheckPoint.x;
        if(TestMax.y < CheckPoint.y)
            TestMax.y = CheckPoint.y;
        if(TestMax.z < CheckPoint.z)
            TestMax.z = CheckPoint.z;

        if(TestMin.x > CheckPoint.x)
            TestMin.x = CheckPoint.x;
        if(TestMin.y > CheckPoint.y)
            TestMin.y = CheckPoint.y;
        if(TestMin.z > CheckPoint.z)
            TestMin.z = CheckPoint.z;

        // If the new bounding box is too big, lets break it off.
        if(fabs(TestMax.x - TestMin.x) > 100 || fabs(TestMax.y - TestMin.y) > 100 || fabs(TestMax.z - TestMin.z) > 50){

            std::vector<XYZ>(CurrMemblock.PointsArr).swap(CurrMemblock.PointsArr);

            return false;

        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

Here is the segment of code using this..

```
                    if(Check_MemBlock_Size(*MemBlock, NewPoint) == false){

                        Data->MemoryBlocks.push_back(MemBlock);

                        try {
                            MemBlock = new MemoryBlock();
                        } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
                            printf("Not enough memory\n");
                            delete Buffer;
                            break;
                        }

                        BlockSize = 0;

                        try{
                            MemBlock->PointsArr.reserve(MaxBlockSize);
                        } catch(std::bad_alloc){
                            delete MemBlock;
                            delete Buffer;
                            printf("Not enough memory\n");
                            break;
                        }

                    }


                    // Push the point to our current memory block
                    BlockSize++;
                    MemBlock->PointsArr.push_back(NewPoint);

                    .... // More stuff going on here.. irrelevant

                    // push a new memory block if we hit the block point limit.
                    if(BlockSize >= MaxBlockSize){

                        Data->MemoryBlocks.push_back(MemBlock);

                        try {
                            MemBlock = new MemoryBlock();
                        } catch (std::bad_alloc) {
                            printf("Not enough memory\n");
                            delete Buffer;
                            break;
                        }

                        BlockSize = 0;

                        try{
                            MemBlock->PointsArr.reserve(MaxBlockSize);
                        } catch(std::bad_alloc){
                            printf("Not enough memory\n");
                            delete MemBlock;
                            delete Buffer;
                            break;
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: Every memory allocation has the potential to cause memory fragmentation.

Comment: I think C++11 vector::shrink_to_fit and move constructors (instead of copying when growing) could alleviate your problems. Is C++11 on option?

Comment: C++11 is not an option.  I understand every allocation can cause some fragmentation, but not the the degree I am seeing.

Comment: Are you using a custom allocator (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)?

Comment: Not using a custom allocator. cannot use c++11. :(

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? are you storing all your data in vectors of 50k size and when your vector becomes greater than 50K making a new vector?

Comment: I'm wondering... isn't the default implementation of the vector good enough? From what I see you are trying to help the std::vector with its allocations but in the end the solution you wrote produces worse results right?

Comment: You should show your code that performs the resize/swap instead of describing it.

Comment: I need the vectors max size of 50k.. If the spatial dimensions are to large, that vector needs to be cut off at 5k size.. If I do not swap the array, there will be wasted memory.

Comment: I use reserve for performance reasons. I will have a max of 50k objects in my vector.  If I allow the default implementation to resize my vector, I think I will run into more wasted memory?

Comment: Is it a 32 bit app with 3G user memory segments? The problem sounds like heap fragmentation. Do you have access to some HeapWalk thing? I'd run a small statistics function in new_handler to make sure.

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve by shrinking the vector? You say you're trying to prevent "wasted memory", but the code you posted shrinks a vector then adds more elements to it.  Is the "wasted" memory actually causing a problem? If you have a max of 50k elements can you just `reserve(50000)` and stop all the copying and reallocating?

Comment: Also why does your code have naked `new` and `delete`, are you a time traveller from the 1990s?

Comment: @user1000247 *"Not using a custom allocator. cannot use c++11"* - Of course you know that custom allocators are *not* a C++11 feature but have existed in standardized C++ since ever.

Comment: @christian,  I was answering two people at one time. That came out confusing.

Comment: @jonathan  My reserve for each memory block is 50k, I am loading much more data than that.. Each block has a spatial position/dimension to it. The reason for shrinking it is to maintain a small spatial dimension..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This technique seems to guarantee fragmentation if in-between calls to `Check_MemBlock_Size()` you do some more dynamic allocation. This is because you release your 50K allocation after allocating your smaller chunk, creating a 50K object hole in memory, which can now be partially filled by some more memory, which your next rebuild of your `MemoryBlock` cannot use.

You could create a global vector instead of a temporary one to hold this 50K object allocation. Then, when you next rebuild a new `MemoryBlock`, instead of resizing a new 50K object vector, just swap in the global one. When you want to shrink it, swap out with the global one again. Reusing the 50K reserved memory this way will remove any fragmentation to which this allocation may have contributed.

However, there may be other sources of fragmentation in your program if you are sure there are no leaks. Typically, fragmentation is caused by a mix of large and small objects dynamically allocated, each with varying lifetimes. There are many ways to resolve it, but one way to handle it is with pools of memory. A pool in this sense is a collection of objects of the same size and same lifespan, grouped together within a custom allocator. Deallocation of such memory is returned to its pool. If the memory is never returned to the system with `delete`, the pool combats fragmentation by allowing future allocations to reuse memory that was allocated previously for the same object type. The pools grow to the peak runtime utilization, and the fragmentation is never worse than that.

Comment: @user1000247: What do you mean by that?

Comment: same problem is happening.

Comment: @user1000247: You may have another source of fragmentation, or you are not actually reusing the 50K pre-allocated vector.

Comment: I went ahead and marked as the answer. I do think you are correct, even though it is not working properly yet. I will keep working on it